# Fetching Response value

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

In Java script i have a variable that holds the value &name=John&age=12&roll=2
for ex:

```
var data =  "&name=John&age=12&roll=2"
```

How can I separately fetch these three values? ie value of name, age and roll

Answer (score 0):

`var data =  "&name=John&age=12&roll=2".split("&")` gives you an array of pairs.

`thisData= data[0].split("=")` gives you `thisData[0]` = "name" and `thisData[1]` = "John"

You can write a loop to extract all of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.split first split it by "&" and then "="

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataparts = data.split("&");
for(var i =0;i<dataparts.length;i++){
     var part = dataparts[i]; 
//do something with the dataparts here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by & leaving out the first & and then by = and get the value at 1

```
var data =  "&name=John&age=12&roll=2";
var datas =data.substr(1,data.length).split('&');
for(var i =0; i<datas.length;i++){
    alert(datas[i].split('=')[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but what if data =  "&name=<name="john">&age=12&roll=2";